# Grouping Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to figure out what is the regular expression for the following situation, where I want to match one of the follwoing if returned back.

```
               ABC 1 or 
               ABC 1 0  or
               ABC 1 0 1  or 
               ABC 1 0 1 0 or etc
```

I'm trying the following to acheive this but its only matching the first string (ABC 1).

```
               regular expression: ABC (1|0)+
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to include a combination of *spaces* and 1s and 0s probably?

Comment: `ABC( (1|0))+` perhaps? Or `ABC( 1 0)*( 1)?` if you must have alternating 0's and 1's.

Comment: I'd probably try ``ABC(\s(1|0))+``

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure it's first a 1, then a 0, then another 1, then a 0 etc, you might use this:

```
re.match(r'ABC(?: 1(?: 0|$))+$', s)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lV1kN8)

EDIT: If you don't care about the order, you can use this:

```
re.match(r'ABC(?: [01])+$', s)
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to change from 0 to 1. I just have a response where I have a string and numbers.

Comment: @user2796819 There was someone else who had posted an answer with a regex to match any order, but he deleted his answer and I don't know why :( Anyway, see if the second regex works for you!

Answer (score 0):

`ABC1(01)*0?`

ABC, then 1, then zero or more 0 1, and finally an optional 0. Assuming you don't want white spaces, of course.

If you want a single space after each "part":

`ABC 1( 0 1)*( 0)?`

Comment: To the downvoters: I believe you are mistaken. The way I understand the question, he wants "ABC" and then a sequence of 1's and 0's, alternating, ending in either a 1 or a 0. I was neglecting whitespace, of course.